# How to count all the enums in a SQL table

Tags: sql, enums, count

Okay so I have a database field called `moderated`

It is an ENUM with 3 values:

```
approved
denied
unmoderated
```

How can I write a query that counts the amount of each, so I can generate this output:

```
Approved: 3
Denied: 10
Unmoderated: 23
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can write like this:

```
Select Moderated, Count(Moderated)  FROM YourTable
Group BY Moderated
```

If you want output in "approved: 3" format, you can add `"Convert(Varchar(10), Moderated) + ':' + Convert(Varchar(10), Count(Moderated))"` to you column list in you select statement.